# What is the command for listing all files ending in small letters?

Tags: unix

suppose i have 'n' number of files such as apple,BAT,comas,aba,abc,abc03.....etc

also
What is the command for listing all files which end in small letters but not ‘a’ and ‘c’?
or any specific character

Answer (score 3):

On bash:

```
$ LC_ALL=C
$ ls
bar  BAT  cab  foo  ieee2000  MAC  moc  test  zac  zara  ZOO
$ ls *[a-z]
bar  cab  foo  moc  test  zac  zara
$ ls *[bd-z]
bar  cab  foo  test
$ ls *[^cC]
bar  BAT  cab  foo  ieee2000  test  zara  ZOO
$ ls *[^bc]
bar  BAT  foo  ieee2000  MAC  test  zara  ZOO
```

Since these are [shell expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) you can also use them in loops etc relatively easily.

Note the `LC_ALL=C` setting - if you use a non-English locale it may be required in order to produce correct results:

```
$ echo $LC_COLLATE
en_US.UTF-8
$ ls *[a-z]
bar  BAT  cab  foo  MAC  moc  test  zac  zara  ZOO
$ LC_COLLATE=C
$ ls *[a-z]
bar  cab  foo  moc  test  zac  zara
```

As seen in  the sample above you can set the more specific `LC_COLLATE` variable instead of `LC_ALL`.

EDIT:

By the way, at least on my system (Mandriva Linux 2010.1), the locale also affects `grep`:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
$ echo A | grep '[a-z]'
A
$ LC_COLLATE=C
$ echo A | grep '[a-z]'
$
```

Comment: I don't think there's any locales (still in use) where `*[bd-z]` would match differently.  Certainly not any UTF-8 locales.

Comment: Hmm, you're right.  `fnmatch` applies collation to ranges but not `[x]` single characters (which is what led me to believe the above).  That seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of ls and grep with regular expressions:

```
ls | grep -e "[bd-z]$"
```